# .net 6 core api get data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

net i have this Controller that gets data from a table :

Entity/model :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace ESM_DASHBOARD.Data.Entities
{
    [Keyless]
    public class wareh_KPI_IN
    {
        public int total_in { get; set; }
        public Decimal price { get; set; }
        public double total_value { get; set; }
        public int Week_nb { get; set; }    
        public int Month_nr { get; set; }
    }}
```

this is the code  :

```
using ESM_DASHBOARD.Data;
using ESM_DASHBOARD.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ESM_DASHBOARD.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class wareh_KPI_INController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly EsmDashboardContext _esmDashboardContext;
        public wareh_KPI_INController(EsmDashboardContext esmDashboardContext)
        {
            _esmDashboardContext = esmDashboardContext;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var wareh_KPI_INs = await _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN.ToArrayAsync();
            return Ok(wareh_KPI_INs);
        }
    }
}
```

i tried to add this but its not working it displays (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

```
        [HttpGet("{Week_nb}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int Week_nb)
        {
            var wareh_KPI_INs = await _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN.FindAsync(Week_nb);
            return Ok(wareh_KPI_INs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is your Week_nb ? Which line has  this null error ?

Comment: Do you set the breakpoint at `wareh_KPI_INs`?  Can you get the value?

Comment: @QingGuo i get all the data on the table (first code ) but i want to specific the week nr

Comment: Have your problem been solved ? If not, try to check your  if your `_esmDashboardContext ` have the data about wareh_KPI_IN  by `int Week_nb`. Could you get the value of `var wareh_KPI_INs = await _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN.FindAsync(Week_nb);` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your action, specify that the variable of `Week_nb` is read from route :

```
[HttpGet("{Week_nb}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int Week_nb)
{
    var wareh_KPI_INs = await _esmDashboardContext.wareh_KPI_IN.FindAsync(Week_nb);
    return Ok(wareh_KPI_INs);
}
```